# Aumentar la ID de un TextView con un bucle

Tags: java, android, android-studio

soy nuevo en Android y estoy intentando hacer una tabla de 9x9 que esta llena de TextViews en cada celda.
Y quiero poner numeros de un array con un setText() en cada TextView.

El problema es que no se como hacer para que la id de los TextView sea automatica.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
    int z = 0;
    int contador = 0;

    for(int y = 1; y <= 9; y++) { //Filas
        for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++) { //Columnas


            String nombreCF = "c"+x+"f"+y; //Id de los text view c1f1, c2f1, c3f1...

            contador = 0;

            for(z=z; contador < 1; z++){

                nombreCF.setText(items[z]); //ERROR nombreCF no se le puede poner un setText()
                contador=1;
            }

        }
    }
```

Como podéis ver he intentado que el id del textview sea un string con el numero de fila y columna generados por un bucle pero claro un string no tiene la función setText().

No se si me estoy haciendo un lío pero sabríais ayudarme a realizarlo?

Muchas gracias!

Olvidé poner el array que quiero que tenga. Tiene que haber un un numero por TextView.

> static int[] items = {7,9,2,6,1,5,3,8,4,5,8,3,7,4,2,6,9,1,1,6,4,3,9,8,5,2,7,9,4,8,2,6,3,7,1,5,2,7,5,4,8,1,9,6,3,6,3,1,9,5,7,2,4,8,8,5,7,1,2,9,4,3,6,3,2,6,8,7,4,1,5,9,4,1,9,5,3,6,8,7,2};

Comment: Ahi no le estas asignando a un textview nada, porque no tenes un textview, tenes un string.

Comment: exactamente lo que dice @gbianchi es lo q te pasa... puedes declarar un arreglo que contenga los textView

Comment: Sí se que no tengo un TextView por eso quiero saber como hacerlo porque si yo hago el TextView c1f1, c2f1, c3f1 etc... lo tengo que hacer manualmente uno por uno? es justo lo que quiero evitar.

Answer (score 0):

Podes crear los ids de los textviews con un int, ya que el resource es de ese tipo , esto previene que tengas que crear x `TextViews` en tu layout.

```
final int N = 10; // Cantidad de textviews a crear

final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; // Creamos un array vacio

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // Creamos un nuevo textview
    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);

    // ponemos algunas propiedades al TextView
    rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);

    // Añadimos el textview al linear layout
    myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);

    // guardamos la referencia donde se guardo el texto para accederlo luego
    myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
}
```

De esta forma creamos TextViews de manera dinamica, y se los asignamos a un `LinearLayout` para poder visualizarlos.

Comment: Estoy probando el código pero no entiendo el myLinearLayout a que corresponde. Yo en mi layout tengo un LinearLayout pero no se si tengo que cambiarle el nombre o ponerle una id o algo así? Gracias.

Comment: LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

Comment: Tenés que agregar esa línea en el código , no hace falta tocar ningún XML, agrégalo antes del for

Comment: Vale ahora tengo los 81 textview que quiero crear y al hacer el setText de items[z] con el bucle que tenía se supone que cada textview tiene un numero. Pero al iniciar la activity se me cierra sin ningún error. En el layout xml tengo que poner linear layout? lo dejo vacío¿? o como? Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Si, debes colocar un linear layout en tu XML con orientación vertical, recuerda que si son muchos quizás requieras un scrollview